# How to copy a file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file

I want to copy a file from A to B in C#. How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `File.Copy(path, destination)` method:

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

Without any error handling code:

```
File.Copy(path, path2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the FileInfo class.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("a.txt");
fi.CopyTo("b.txt");
```

Comment: This makes an empty file of the same name. It does not copy contents.

Answer (score 2):

This should work!

```
using System.IO;

...

var path = //your current filePath
var outputPath = //the directory where you want your (.txt) file


File.Copy(path,outputPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.File.Copy(path, destination)`