# Count files, if it is one file then copy to another folder

Tags: c#, file

I have counted *how many files* I have in a folder. if it is *one* I want to copy that file to another folder. I want to copy the file to another folder but file. `Copy` *does not accept* `int`. This is my code:

```
var path       = @"C:\Projects\Copy";
var fileType   = @"*.txt";
var fileOutput = @"C:\Projects\Paste";

int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, fileType).Length;

if (fCount == 1)
{
    File.Copy(fCount, fileOutput); // I get stuck here
}
```

Comment: And where did you get stuck? You surely have searched how to copy a file to another folder, what did you try, what didn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933/how-to-copy-a-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Use this System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);

Comment: File.Move(srcFile, destFile);

Comment: before this question gets closed as unclear, please try to be more precise what you are trying to do. "I want to copy the file to another folder but file" this is very hard to understand (at least for me) Why do you try to put an `int` into the method? What are your thoughts behind this action?

Comment: File.Copy does require the filename of the file you want to copy, and you are using the amount of files. You should `string[] existingFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, fileType);` and `File.Copy(existingFiles[0], fileOutput);`

Comment: "unclear what you're asking" might be true, but it was clear what the solution is and what OP was doing wrong.

Comment: @Matt indeed, but very basic problems could look more like a typo and raise closing votes because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if there's *one and only one* file:

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 // Directory.GetFiles returns all files found (e.g. 1234567 files) it can be very slow
 // we want at most 2 files found in order do not start copying:
 string[] files = Directory
   .EnumerateFiles(path, fileType) // not GetFiles
   .Take(2)                        // Take at most 2 files
   .ToArray();   

 // we can have 0, 1 or 2 files (thanks to Take(2)) 
 if (files.Length == 1)
   File.Copy(files[0], Path.Combine(fileOutput, Path.GetFileName(files[0])));
```

If you want to copy files if there's *at least one* file we can skip checking at all

```
 foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, fileType))  
   File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(fileOutput, Path.GetFileName(file)));
```

Please, notice

```
Path.Combine(fileOutput, Path.GetFileName(file))
```

we create a new file name from *target directory* and *original* file name.

Comment: Your code gave me an idea on an performance wise exension method.

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitry. It worked just the way I wanted to work!

Answer (score 0):

try with `File.Copy("C:\Projects\fileToCopy.txt", "C:\pathToNewLocation\copyOfMyFile.txt", true);`
you must give path to `File.Copy` method not int

[Documentation of File.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2)